# including extension methods within interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

When abstracting an interface out from a concrete class, should the interface include the extension methods? The context is specifically for ease-of-unit-testability.

Comment: No, that won't work. If the interface declared the method, the class would have to implement it. You can unit-test the extension method with specific test cases, as it is simply a static method of _another_ class.

Comment: Your question is confusing, because an interface can't contain a class, which is needed to define extension methods.  Are you trying to ask if the class with the extension methods should be contained within the same file as the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you describe the case, I would say no. If your extension methods are clearly only useful in the context of your unittest, then keep them as extension methods in your test project.

The alternative would be to move your extension methods into the class (changing them into normal public methods), and include them in the interface. This would make them available to everything that consumes your class, which is not desirable for unittest code.

Extension methods are great for adding functionality to classes you don't have control over or separating out areas of responsibility. This is a classic example of the latter.

Answer (score 0):

If a class depends on `SomeOtherClass`, and it depends on both instance members *and* static members of `SomeOtherClass`, then you could either

- Change the static members to instance members that can be a part of the interface
- Put the static members in a separate extension class (or some other dependency) so that `SomeOtherClass` can be replaced with an interface.

By using both instance and static members of the dependency, it effectively becomes two dependencies in one. You're depending on the object (instance members) and on the object's type (static members.)

If the methods are required by the class itself in order to function then they should probably be members of that class. If they are needed in order for other classes to use that class in ways that are outside that class's responsibility (like a method that maps a class to some other class) then I'd separate it out.

If the methods are both - required by the class and required by other classes, then you could separate it into another class that both the original class and other classes can depend on.

Answer (score 0):

No. You have a few problems with this. First, interfaces describe only the *signature* of public *instance* methods (i.e. they mayn't have implementations and you mayn't specify a static method in an interface). Extension methods must have an implementation at compile time and they aren't instance methods, they're static methods. Note at this point that according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

> In your code you invoke the extension method with instance method
>   syntax. However, the intermediate language (IL) generated by the
>   compiler translates your code into a call on the static method.

In other words, it's not *really* an instance method (even if you can treat it like one); "under the hood" it's still a static method.

Also, extension methods have to be defined in a static class (see Microsoft's [instructions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311042.aspx) on how to implement an extension method).

Note that you *can* have an extension method on an interface; there's no requirement that the type you're extending be concrete. For example:

```
public static class Class2
{
    public static void Extension(this ITestInterface test)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("This is allowed");
    }
}
```

Now when I instantiate a concrete class that implements the ITestInterface interface I can call the extension method on it:

```
// "Test" is some class that implements the ITestInterface interface
ITestInterface useExtensionMethod = new Test();
useExtensionMethod.Extension();
```

This could do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

By way of example, for the following two classes:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public Prop1 { get; }
    public void Method1() { .... }
}

static class SomeExtensions
{
    public static ExtensionMethod(SomeClass this sc) { ... }
}
```

As others have said, when creating the interface, you are limited to the public, non-static members in `SomeClass`, however, it's also worth modifying the extension method to refer to the interface, rather than the concrete type at the same time:

```
static class SomeExtensions
{
    public static ExtensionMethod(ISomeClass this sc) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Yes, good point, I edited my answer to reflect the fact that an extension method may take an interface as parameter type as well - I think that this could do what he's looking for (even if the interface itself doesn't *literally* contain the extension method). IMHO this is probably a better practice than doing the extension method on the concrete class so that you're being consistent about programming against interfaces rather than concrete classes.